# Retain selected image from gallery to a new activity in android

Tags: android, image

i want to select an image from gallery and display the same in next activity. On implementing , no image gets retained .

Here is my code :
Activity 1 :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bot=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buk1);
    bot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(); 
            intent.setType("image/*"); 
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);// 
            //startActivity(intent);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),10);

        }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
     Bitmap selectedphoto   = null;
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) 
    {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String [] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();       
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        selectedphoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        cursor.close();
        Intent i = new Intent (MainAct.this,gal.class);
        i.putExtra("data",selectedphoto);
        startActivity(i); 
    }

}
```

Activity 2:

```
         public class gal extends Activity{
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imger);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.galr);

        Bitmap selectedphoto  =(Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
        view.setImageBitmap(selectedphoto);
    }

}
```

Comment: see here http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the selected images.
2. Put them in an `ArrayList<Bitmap>`.
3. Put it in extras of your `Intent`.
4. Retrieve in next activity.

Answer (score 0):

Passing bitmap through intent can be very expansive so pass the path and decode again

Try it this way -

```
Intent i = new Intent (MainAct.this,gal.class);
        i.putExtra("data",filePath);
        startActivity(i);
```

in gal activity get the path and decode bitmap again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing bitmap to ShowImage activity, pass your URI and then retrieve actual bitmap in ShowImage activity exactly as you do now in your PictureOptions activity.

```
intent.setData( uri );
```

In your ShowImage activity do:

```
URI imageUri = getIntent().getData();
```